# How to display all images of a folder serially in node.js

Tags: node.js, image, displayobject

I have 51 images in a folder how do I display all the images serially? the code is given below.

```
var i = "hamarabajaj_"; 
var p = 0; 
var q = 0; 
var r = ".png"; 
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'); 

p = p+1; 
q = i+p+r; 
fs.readFile('/home/bidya271/Documents/Health_Monitor/pictures/'+q, function(err, data) {                                  
    if (err) throw err; 
    http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'});     
        res.end(data); // Send the file data to the browser.
    }).listen(8124);    
    console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8124/');      
});
```

Comment: On the website .
we would like to display all our images from a particular folder to the server one after the other with the images getting over-written in the server

Comment: What's the problem?  Simply have an `<img>` element for each image and serve them from your web server.

Comment: @Brad can you help me out with the full code....my images filename is hamarabajaj_1.png,hamarabajaj_2.png, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what your goal is, but it is impossible to "serially" send images from a  HTTP server to a client. However, you can make a make a server that takes a request from a client and returns images on demand.

Below is an example of a server that serves up images based upon an image prefix:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    imageDir = __dirname + "/pictures/",
    imageSuffix = "-image.png",
    fs = require("fs");

app.get("/images/:id", function (request, response) {
    var path = imageDir + request.params.id + imageSuffix;

    console.log("fetching image: ", path);
    response.sendFile(path);
});


app.listen(8080);
```

The above code uses the [Express](http://expressjs.com/) to easily bootstrap a web server; you can install it with `npm install express`.

Assuming that you add pictures to the "pictures" folder, you can request images in you browser by hitting the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/images/0
```

which would return the image at `pictures/0-image.png`. `/1` would return `1-image.png` and so on.